# shouldOverrideUrlLoading only if continuing on same site

Tags: android, webview, adt

Im using a webview to display my website in an app, and shouldOverrideUrlLoading to keep the links in it, however, I only want the links that continue on my website to override, other links such as facebook sharing link I want to open externally.

Please, how can I shouldOverrideUrlLoading only if the url = mysite.com, thank you!

```
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the `url` variable to check if the url is inside your domain.

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  URI obj = new URI(url);
  if (!"mysite.com".equals(obj.getHost()) {
    return false;
  } 

  view.loadUrl(url);
  return true;
}
```

Change `mysite.com` with your domain host.

(*you will need to handle www. cases too*)

Comment: Pardon my inexperience, I'm a PHP guy, this is my first experience with Android / Java. Where should that go? The places I've tried show errors in Eclipse.

Comment: Inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. Edited post